# Setting a value in a 2d array causes others in array to change

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm new to C++, and I think there's some concept I'm missing because all I'm trying to do is set a value in a 2d array and it's messing up. Instead of just setting it once in the location I specify, it sets it in multiple locations. The code makes perfect sense in other languages, so it must be some quirk of C++ that I don't know?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
const int width=26;
const int height=10;
char arr[width][height];
//fill with dots
std::string empty=".";
for (int i=0;i<height;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<width;j++)
    {
        arr[i][j]=empty[0];
    }
}
std::string msg="test";
//set location row=5, col=3 to "t"
arr[5][3]=msg[0];

//print the array
for (int i=0;i<height;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<width;j++)
    {
        std::cout<<arr[i][j];
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
}
```

The result is:

```
..........................
..........................
..........................
.......................t..
............t.............
...t......................
..........................
..........................
..........................
..........................
```

There should only be 1 t in the middle. I don't understand why it's putting the other 2 t's.

Comment: What are height and width? Could you post code that actually compiles?

Comment: With `height` as 10 and `width` as 26, it produces the same result: http://ideone.com/cXXof. I presume the OP couldn't figure out how to declare them as constant expressions for the array dimensions.

Comment: By the way, the indices in question are [y][x]: [5][3], [4][13], and [3][23]. I get the feeling I'm going to kick myself hard when the behaviour is figured out.

Comment: oh sorry, I originally had the constants set but then accidentally removed those while cleaning the code up to post here. height is 10 and width is 26

Comment: Heheh `5*10+3 == 4*10+13 == 3*10+23`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the shape of the output, you're obviously using height of 10 and width of 26.

You are referencing the array as `[i][j]` where `i` is vertical and `j` is horizontal, but in that case the array is defined with 26 rows and 10 columns.  So you are overflowing it when you print out.  The array is just a contiguous block of memory, so this isn't overflowing that block.  Otherwise you'd have a crash.  But it is incorrect.

Your rows are currently 10 chars long but you are accessing as if they are 26.  This means you  take values from the next 2 rows.  The extra 't' values in the output are the result of overflowing in the rows before them.

Hope this makes sense.

Either change the accesses to `arr[j][i]`, or the definition to `char arr[10][26]`.

Comment: Note that it is sometimes easier to use 'y' and 'x' as your loop variables instead of `i` and `j`.  That avoids the confusion of which is row and column...  unless you are a mathematician =)

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe I missed that. That makes me feel sort of better that it was just me being blind instead of C++ being completely different than stuff I know like Java :P

Answer (score 3):

It has to do with how you are defining **height** and **width**.

Since you didn't give the value you are using in your example code I tried both options.

With:

```
int  height = 10;
int  width = 26;
```

You get the behavior you described above.

However with:

```
int  height = 26;
int  width = 10;
```

You get the correct behavior, the reason you were seeing the 't' multiple times is because with the height and width defined with the incorrect values you just happened to be indexing the same point in memory because you were over running the buffer into memory that you had just happened to have correctly initialized.